# filesystem API versus mmap for /dev/shm

Tags: shared-memory, mmap

I have a hard time understanding the *recommended* way to use shared memory on Linux systems, especially how I am supposed to share them.

- `/dev/shm` is backed by the page-cache. Essentially this is an in-memory filesystem.
- `mmap()` is a syscall that allows to create a new virtual memory chunk that is backed by either fresh new memory or an existing file.

I like `/dev/shm`, because it allows me to use pretty much all the tooling available for regular filesystems.
I also like `mmap`, because it allows me to access files without buffering.

Bit I just can't really get my head around the usage of `mmap` on files in `/dev/shm`.

If I want to create a shared memory for a set of processes, is it enough to just create a file in `/dev/shm` and use all the existing filesystem calls (`open`, `read`, `write`, ...)? considering the subprocesses only require a file-like interface with the shared memory.

Why do I see most people `mmap`ing shared memories in `/dev/shm`? Are `write`/`read` in `/dev/shm` buffered in any way? Why would you not just `open(/dev/shm/something)` and `read()`/`write()` in it directly?

Also, can I have my subprocesses concurrently write at distinct locations of the shared memory (through filesystem APIs like `read`/`write` of memory APIs like `memcpy`) without any issue?

Basically, my end goal is to create a shared memory the size of a remote file, then have multiple processes download chunks of the file concurrently in the shared memory, and finally load the resulting file for processing.